# "Visited link" on Moderator tag almost impossible to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

Says it all really.

Running Chrome v6.0.472.63 - no changes from the defaults w.r.t. link colours etc. - on Windows XP.

I'm getting the same effect on Firefox (3.6.7) and IE 8

Comment: What browser is that showing up on?

Comment: @Eight - Chrome - I'll update the question

Comment: Got the same version, don't see the same on a Vista machine

Comment: You've cleared your cache too, yes?

Comment: @Eight - I only use Chrome for posting on any SE site, so I hadn't visited using Firefox or IE and certainly not since the design went live

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes I see the same thing, I'm using Chrome 6.0.472.63.  I confirmed that on firefox it displays in a readable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChrisF, I can repro. Fix is on the way!